# Exception while attaching existing child entities in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, change-tracking

I'm using Entity Framework in an unconventional way to track changes in a Winforms application. Basically, I load data through API calls and attach data into the context to display in grid controls.

I've some requirement to display one to one relation based navigational property in grid column (plenty of such columns). In order to achieve this, the tracking part was required. I'm using the [Local Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/local-data) concept after attaching the entities.

Here's is a simplified example of the problem

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Loading & Attaching records into the context
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
     // Get list of Students with Department data from API
     var students = GetStudents();

     foreach (var record in students )
     {
         var existingEntry = Set<T>().Local.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id== record.Id);

         if (existingEntry != null)
         {
             this.Entry(existingEntry).CurrentValues.SetValues(record);
             this.Entry(existingEntry).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
         }
         else
         {
             // Throws exception because some students belong to same department and that department is already attached
             Set<T>().Attach(record);
         }
    }
}
```

I understand that checking the existence only works on the student level but still the problem occurs for department data. In the real implementation, I've a lot of navigational properties (on an average 15 per entity) including collections. Also, the API retrieval and attaching context is a generic implementation (in place of `GetStudents()` method, I call some other method with some API route which retrieves list of data based on some OData query).

What should be a suitable approach other than using reflection to check the existence of all navigation properties for each record before attaching?

Comment: In a nutshell: Don't. Entities should "live" only as long as their DbContext. Views should use view models with just the data that the view/grid needs that is projected from the entities. The entity graphs can be re-loaded from the database when needed based on IDs.  APIs should never deliver, and especially should not attach and update entities as you should never trust data coming in. It is possible to modify everything in a passed entity model to corrupt your data state.

Comment: @StevePy Thanks a lot for your quick response. I agree with you on the Entities & Viewmodel part. I think I was not able to explain the problem clearly. The code snippet and the context in my example is a context on the client (WinForms) not on API. 

Basically, I make a request to API to provide the data and then I'm trying to attach the response from the API into the context used in WinForms application for further tracking. This WinForms context which I'm trying to use is not connected with any database.